# timestamp difference of two files in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to get the time difference between the newest file and the oldest file in a specified directory using shell script, Can anyone help on this

As an example, lets see below scenario, I have a directory which contains several files and directories, I need to get the exact time difference between the newest and oldest file in this directory.

Here is the directroy and contained files and directories by using `ls -lrt`:

```
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:Downloads ik$ ls -lrt
total 682992
drwxr-xr-x  27 ik  staff        918 Oct  7 23:09 Temp
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff  169544881 Oct  8 00:39 filmora-mac_full2074.dmg
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff     445446 Oct 13 07:46 4670-lecture7-plsql.pptx
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff     166136 Oct 13 09:29 IT 5080 Devops Module Outline.pdf
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff      13547 Oct 13 09:34 IoTProjectGroups_2018_s2.docx
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff   15546624 Oct 13 09:58 node-v8.12.0.pkg
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff      80533 Oct 16 17:39 CC_Presentation1.pptx
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff     186791 Oct 16 23:14 Assignment_2018.pdf
drwxr-xr-x@  3 ik  staff        102 Oct 17 15:12 Mountain Duck.app
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff     456243 Oct 17 20:31 canvasjs.min.js
drwx------@ 39 ik  staff       1326 Oct 18 05:31 SolarIOT1_files
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff      43637 Oct 19 19:03 logo-fav.png
-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff       7246 Oct 19 19:05 rsz_logo-fav.png
```

As per above the newest and oldest file is as below

Newest file : `-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff       7246 Oct 19 19:05 rsz_logo-fav.png`

Oldest file : `-rw-r--r--@  1 ik  staff  169544881 Oct  8 00:39 filmora-mac_full2074.dmg`

So once I run this program I need to get the time difference :-> 11 days, 18 hours, 26 minutes and 0 seconds

Comment: A dirty solution I would use for getting the diff in seconds, `echo $(( $(date "+%s" -r "$(ls -1t | head -1)") - $(date "+%s" -r "$(ls -1t | tail -1)") ))`. Of course you must [read this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the difference of the modification times, this does the trick:

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\n' | sort -n | awk 'NR==1 {first=$0} END{print $0-first}'
```

- `-maxdepth 1` - Search in the current dir only
- `-type f` - Search for files only
- `-printf '%T@\n'` - Print with a specific format. In this case it prints the modification time in seconds.
- `NR==1 {first=$0}` - If it's the first line, save the line in a variable
- `END{print $0-first}` - When the end of the input is reached, substract the first line from this one (the last)

Comment: No, I need to get the time difference between the oldest file and newest file inside the same directory, not the modification time. Can you please help.

Comment: Please define what you mean by `oldest` and `newest`. Do you mean by creation time?

Comment: Yes, I have a directory, there is a separate scheduler to move files to that directory, I need to check the time difference of newest and the oldest file after scheduler moves the files into the directory

Comment: Getting the initial creation date/time is going to be difficult unless you had some file system auditing set up.

Comment: Creation (birth) times are generally not stored in the filesystem. To know when the file was **moved** to that directory (not created), you can use `%C@` instead of `%T@` in the find command.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you and will show you  diff in second

Code:

```
 echo `stat -c%Y first_file` - `stat -c%Y second_file` | bc
```

You could divide by 60 to learn the # minutes
Divide again by 60 to learn # hours
And divide by 24 to learn the # days